# What drivers is windows currently using for my mouse?

Tags: windows-7, windows, drivers, mouse

I'm trying to find my mouse driver, so I can reverse-engineer it.

The mouse I'm currently using has a problem with reversed thumb buttons.

I want to decompile the driver and change the way those two buttons are detected, but first I need to find the driver, that's used for my mouse.

I'm currently running Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably used to Linux, but Windows is closed proprietary system
and its code is unpublished.

I suggest searching for a driver on the manufacturer's Support website.
If one is not found, and the configuration at Control Panel -> Mouse doesn't
offer a solution, your only other option is to use a product such
as [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/)
to switch the thumb buttons.

Comment: Thank you, you are my saviour. Driver files are indeed shown in mouse settings.

Comment: Also, AutoHotkey doesn't work for me, as some applications like discord detect both buttons being pressed.

Comment: Can still be done, but requires a clever AHK script that differentiates between button-down and button-up.